# Bokeh: vbar not updating but circles do

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm building a simple plot with bokeh 0.12.13 with a slider to dynamically update. Everything works nicely with circles but not with vbar and I do not understand why.
See code below

```
def update_title(attrname, old, new):
    ''' Update figure title when text box changes'''
    plot.title.text = text.value

def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    ''' Update graph using a slider '''
    # Get the current slider values
    q = quantile.value
    # Generate the new curve
    X = np.array(range(len(sample_data[q].Index)))+0.35
    Y = sample_data[q].Index_reported_Rate
    source.data = dict(x=X, y=Y)

text = TextInput(title="title", value='Enter text')
quantile = Slider(start=0, end=5, value=1, step=1, title="quantile")

X = sample_data[0].Index.values
Y = sample_data[quantile.value].Index_reported_Rate.values
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=X, top=Y))
# Source below works for circles
# source_c = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=X, y=Y))

# Definition of the figure
plot = figure(plot_width=500,
              plot_height=500,
              x_axis_label=selected_factor,
              x_range=sample_data[quantile.value].Index.values,
              title="Figure"
              )

plot.circle(x='x',
            y='y',
            source=source_c,
            size=20
            )

### Set up callbacks
text.on_change('value', update_title)
quantile.on_change('value', update_data)

### Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = widgetbox(text, quantile)
curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot, width=500))
curdoc().title = "Sliders"
```

So this code works perfectly fine (except I can't update the axes yet) but if I replace plot.circle with vbar as shown below, then it does not work.
By "not working", I mean that when I run the server, the figure displays the bars but values do not change when I slide the slider....

```
plot.vbar(x='x',
          top='top', 
          source=source,
          width=0.25,
          bottom=0,         
          color='red'
          )
```

Comment: I'd be happy to investigate, but would need a complete script that could be run.

Comment: Comment edited. I'll update sample file with sample data

Comment: Well, with a sample data set both vbars and circles work ... I must have missed something. I'll answer as soon as I fix everything ...